# How to access the keys inside an object whose name is dynamic in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "Continent": "Asia",
  "Countries": {
    "South Korea": {
      "GDP": 80,
      "HGI": 60,
      "FX": 10
    },
    "India": {
      "GDP": 75,
      "HGI": 112,
      "FX": 28
    },
    "Singapore": {
      "GDP": 34,
      "HGI": 60,
      "FX": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I have the above JSON. Need to access the GDP and HGI fields. But the name of the country changes as per continent. How to create a single query by which I can access the GDP and HGI? Is something like referencing position of the key inside an object possible?
I cannot convert this to array. Need to extract data from this format only.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You can do this using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/ What exactly are you trying to query?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator

The query would look like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "countries": {
        "$objectToArray": "$Countries"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "countries.v.GDP": 1
    }
  }
])
```

results:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "countries": [
      {
        "v": {
          "GDP": 80
        }
      },
      {
        "v": {
          "GDP": 75
        }
      },
      {
        "v": {
          "GDP": 34
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/1ODRczeV-0S](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1ODRczeV-0S)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get all the countries of a continent you can process the data with a small trick i.e.

```
 {
   "_id": "1",
   "Continent": "Asia",
   "Countries": {
     "South Korea": {
       "GDP": 80,
       "HGI": 60,
       "FX": 10
     },
     "India": {
       "GDP": 75,
       "HGI": 112,
       "FX": 28
     },
     "Singapore": {
       "GDP": 34,
       "HGI": 60,
       "FX": 0
     }
   }
 }
```

from above you can easily get Countries. Now,

```
Object.keys(data.Countries);
```

this will return you all the countries in an array i.e. ["South Korea", "India", "Singapore"]. Now you can easily access all the country-specific data by accessing these keys.